# How to get ordered items in observer for "sales_order_place_after" event?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, sales

I am trying to get ordered items in sales_order_place_after event,
but i am not able to log the ordered items.

Here is the code which i have used.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Directory\Model\Currency;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Segment;

class Tracking extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;
    private $segment;
    private $currency;
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title $pageTitle,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Currency $currency,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Segment $segment
    ) {
        $this->redirect              = $redirect;
        $this->_pageTitle            = $pageTitle;
        $this->_segment              = $segment;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->orderRepository       = $orderRepository;
        $this->storeManager          = $storeManager;
        $this->currency              = $currency;
    }
    /**
     * @param object $order
     * Process order data & track order completed event
     */
    public function trackOrderCompleted($order)
    {
        if (!$order) {
            return;
        }

        $orderItems = array();

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('increment_id', $order['increment_id'])->create();
        $orderData = [];
        $order     = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        if ($order->getTotalCount()) {
            $orderData = $order->getItems();
        }
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/orderData.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($orderData);
        print_r($orderData);exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> $logger->info(json_encode($orderData));

You should encode to JSON the objects or arrays.